# Javascript. Неясное поведение цикла

Tags: javascript

После вызова TurnOFFALL, на второй итерации цикла код TurnON(срабатывает в ответ на клик из TurnOFFALL) в ветке содержащей console.log(dev+" "+checkbox); на второй итерации происходит непонятно что. При том для 1 и 3 итераций все работает.

[image: Суть проблемы]

```
 <div class="lightblock">
                <center><div class="llabel"><h3>text</h3></div></center>
                <a style="opacity:0.9;" name="fourpins-3" id="fourpins" data-on="0" onclick='TurnChanell(this);'>1</a>
                <a id="fourpins" name="fourpins-3" data-on="0" onclick='TurnChanell(this);'>2</a>
                <a style=" clear: left;" name="fourpins-3" id="fourpins" data-on="0" onclick='TurnChanell(this);'>3</a>
                <a style="opacity:0.9;" name="fourpins-3" id="fourpins" data-on="0" onclick='TurnChanell(this);'>4</a>
                <a href='#' onclick='TurnON(this);' style="float:left;height:40px;width:80px;margin-left:-140px;margin-top:-20px;z-index: 9999;">
                    <div class="switch">
                    <input id="cmn-toggle-3" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="cmn-toggle-3" id="lab3">0</label>
                </div>
                </a>                
            </div>

function TurnON(checkbox){
            if(count!=0){ count=0;}
            else{ 
                var dev = checkbox.getElementsByTagName("LABEL")[0].htmlFor.replace("cmn-toggle-", "");
                if(checkbox.getElementsByTagName("LABEL")[0].innerText == '1'){
                    console.log(dev+" "+checkbox);                    
                    checkbox.getElementsByTagName("LABEL")[0].innerText = 0;                    
                    var el = document.getElementsByName("fourpins-"+dev);
                    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
                        if(el[i].getAttribute("data-on") == "1")
                            el[i].click();
                    }
                }else{                
                    checkbox.getElementsByTagName("LABEL")[0].innerText = 1;
                    var el = document.getElementsByName("fourpins-"+dev);
                    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
                        if(el[i].getAttribute("data-on") == "0")
                            el[i].click();
                    }                   
                }
                count++;
            }
        }

        function TurnOFFALL(){
            for(var i = 1;i <= 3;i++) {               
                if( document.getElementById('lab'+i).innerText == "1"){                   
                    document.getElementById('cmn-toggle-'+i).click();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что проблема тут:

```
if(count!=0){ count=0;}
else{
```

В первой итерации у вас count равен 0 и выполняется блок else, увеличивая count. Во второй итерации count не равен 0 и выполняется блок, делающий count равным 0 и не выполняющий ваш код. Так как count сделали равным 0, третья итерация выполняется.